# How to get a graph with the best performing runs via Sweeps (Weights & Biases)?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition, wandb

For my NER model I use Weights & Biases sweeps for hyperparameter search. I do a grid search with about 100 runs and there are some really meaningful graphs. However, I can't figure out how to create a graph that shows about the best 10 runs in terms of f-score. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hey, can you share your sweep page?

Comment: Here it is: https://wandb.ai/benelanger/jr-skilldetection-service?workspace=user-

Comment: I have set the access back to private because the question was answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sweep view, you can filter runs by certain criteria by clicking this button:
[image]

There, you can add a filter to only show runs with an f1 score, or an accuracy or whatever metric you have logged higher than a certain value:
[image]

Of course, this won't filter for the 10 best runs, but for all runs with an accuracy of 0.9 and higher (example in picture).

Comment: I tried that too, but I didn't find "accuracy". But your solution works for me with "score" (which I think is accuracy) and "ents_f". So thanks a lot for your help :)

But I wonder, can you actually filter by "accuracy"?

Comment: You should find all values you have logged in your runs. If you logged the f1-score as 'score', you can filter by score.